# @JvmOverloads error on kotlin interface companion object function

Tags: kotlin, annotations, overloading, jvm-bytecode

Cannot use @JvmOverloads on kotlin interface companion object function, even an @JvmStatic on it:

```
interface Foo {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @JvmOverloads
        fun bar(a: Int = 1, b: Int = 2){}
    }
}
```

No error tipps shows on IDEA when coding, but error shows in compile:

```
Method bar in class Foo has illegal modifiers: 0x19
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method bar in class Foo has illegal modifiers: 0x19
```

### **Problem is solved, this is a bug and fixed in 1.4.20**

Comment: What is your Java version?

Comment: @SeyedMasoodKhademi 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35716) in compiler. Will be fixed in 1.4.20.

Comment: Not fixed in 1.4.20-RC

Answer (score 0):

According to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html:

Default methods are available only for targets JVM 1.8 and above.

Comment: These aren't default methods, they are public static java methods (they are in the kotlin companion object annotated with `@JvmStatic`).